# Spectrogram (Narrow-band, Wide-band) code in Matlab

Tags: matlab, spectrogram

I want the code for demonstration of the spectrogram, narrow-band and wide-band.

I know that there is a function 'specgram'.

```
specgram(signal, nfft, fs, window, nooverlap);
```

But my question is that what should be the values of parameters 'window', 'nooverlap' and 'nfft' in narrow-band and wide-band spectrogram.

singal and fs will come from

```
[signal, fs, bits]=wavread('wavfile.wav');
```

what about others ?

Answer (score 0):

nfft = is a power of 2, length of fft  can be 512, 1024 etc

window is a periodic Hann (Hanning) window of max length nfft, builtin Matlab function

numoverlap = length(window)/2 for 50% overlap between successive frames

You may need to play with the parameter window length